# MQSeries error com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CustomCharsetProvider not a subtype

Tags: ibm-mq

I have an existing java batch process running on windows that writes to an MQSeries queue. 
Works fine in v7, but fails using v8.0.0.3.

Using these jar files:
com.ibm.mq.allclient-8.0.0.3.jar
javax.jms-api-2.0.1.jar
Tried running with both and just the allclient jar, but repeatedly get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.nio.charset.spi.CharsetProvider: Provider com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CustomCharsetProvider not a subtype
               at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)
               at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185)
               at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:376)
               at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404)
               at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset$1.getNext(Charset.java:352)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset$1.hasNext(Charset.java:365)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset$2.run(Charset.java:410)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset$2.run(Charset.java:407)
               at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookupViaProviders(Charset.java:406)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup2(Charset.java:477)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset.lookup(Charset.java:464)
               at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:528)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage$JmqiCodepageFactory.initializeCodepage(JmqiCodepage.java:194)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage$JmqiCodepageFactory.getByName(JmqiCodepage.java:181)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage.getJmqiCodepage(JmqiCodepage.java:661)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiCodepage.getJmqiCodepage(JmqiCodepage.java:637)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getJmqiCodepage(JmqiEnvironment.java:294)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.lookupDefaultCharset(JmqiEnvironment.java:361)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.<init>(JmqiEnvironment.java:262)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.system.JmqiSystemEnvironment.<init>(JmqiSystemEnvironment.java:76)
               at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiFactory.getInstance(JmqiFactory.java:122)
               at com.ibm.mq.internal.MQCommonServices.<clinit>(MQCommonServices.java:146)
               at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.getJmqiEnv(MQSESSION.java:141)
               at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.<init>(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:95)
               at com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment.<clinit>(MQEnvironment.java:569)
```

my code made a call to MQenvironment

Comment: Make sure you do not have any other MQ jar files in the CLASSPATH from other versions of MQ.

Answer (score 1):

This usually occurs when there are conflicting MQ jars which consists of the same classes. You have to remove the unnecessary mq jars before runnig the application

Answer (score 0):

Execute using the java version embedded within the MQClient.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that for your configured CCSID (code-page), charset is not resolved properly and CustomCharsetProvider is used but it does not implement proper interface, which is in my opinion IBM bug).

You have two options to fix it:

1. pass different CCSID (for instance put 1208 which is UTF-8) as MQConstants.CCSID_PROPERTY in your code where you are
   creating MQQueueManager passed as HashMap properties
2. or change CCSID (for instance put 1208 which is UTF-8) at MQ server configuration

Comment: The OP self answered that they used the IBM provided Java to fix this, why do you think it is a CCSID issue?

Comment: issue is that Charset is not found so maybe IBM java has it. But if you do not want to use IBM java for whatever reason you have to change CCSID.
We had same issue and when we changed CCSID to 1208 (UTF-8) - all starts working properly.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  I guess the `Provider com.ibm.mq.jmqi.CustomCharsetProvider not a subtype  at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239)` is what tells you it is a missing Charset?

Answer (score 0):

Check os Lang encoding : set |grep -i Lang

Now check code encoding using trace on

Pass in vmargs if not matching encoding

-Defile.encoding=utf-8